# Apache VFS on Sharepoint mounted as a drive

Tags: sharepoint-2013, apache-commons-vfs

Has anyone used apache vfs on SharePoint 2013 mounted as a drive ?  I am able to mount SharePoint as a drive, but do not know how to use VFS to monitor files in Document Libraries. I am very new to the topic and any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what had to be done. After mounting SharePoint as a network drive, all that was needed to be done is : The java process needed to be run with credentials of the user who has permissions to the SharePoint site. Then, VFS can read the mounted drive as well.